# Можно ли в mongodb изменить поле во всех документах?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Есть коллекция документов с полем скажем `name`. Нужно в каждом документе удалить из имени 3 символа в начале.

Comment: Не понятна суть вопроса: нужно в текстовой строке удалить первые три символа? Или что?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, ты хочешь пройтись по всем документам в коллекции и для каждого поменять значение поля?
Тогда можно сделать так:

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({ %условие поиска% }).forEach(function(e){
   e.name= e.name.slice(3, e.name.length); //Берем строку без 3 первых символов
   db.getCollection('collection').save(e); //Сохраняем
})
```

Не забудь забекапиться ;)